# Django APIView get data from another class

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in Django, I developed a class view which gets data from a form. Using this data I run my algorithms and I want to show the result using a chart. So to send data from the view to the template I used APIview. but my problem is I can't get data from the first class which get data and run algorithm and send the result to the second class API view

```
class GeneticView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'Optimisation/genetics.html'
maxTest = [1,2,3,4]
def get(self, request):
    form = GeneticsForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
def post(self, request):
    form = GeneticsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        NP = form.cleaned_data['NP']
        NGEN = form.cleaned_data['NGEN']
        CXPB = form.cleaned_data['CXPB']
        MUTPB = form.cleaned_data['MUTPB']
        genetic = Genetic(NP, CXPB, MUTPB, NGEN)
        genetic.GeneticMethod()

        #Get the information of the RUN
        best_ind = genetic.get_best()
        run_time = genetic.get_RunTime()

    args = {
        'form': form,
        'best': best_ind,
        'run': run_time,
        'max': genetic.get_max(),
        'min': genetic.get_min(),
        'avg': genetic.get_avg(),
        'std': genetic.get_std(),
    }
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

API class:

```
class ChartData(APIView):

authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = []

def get(self, request, format=None):
    data = {
        'max': [20, 12, 3, 2, 13],
        'min': [10, 2, 3, 8, 5],
    }
    return Response(data)
```

I want from the first send the max and min.
I just tested the API class with some data

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you have so far so we can get some context

Comment: I don't understand what these views have to do with each other, or indeed what you're asking at all.

Comment: the first one get data and use it for runing algorithms and then I want to show the result using chart.js so I need json format this is why i need APIview